# How to open screen on button click which is in another screen using segue and slider menu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

This is [profile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JHq5.png), which contains button with message image.
I want to open message screen on that button click.

So how can I embed or open view beside and with in any view?

Comment: Uh....add a method to the button and segue to your desired VC in that method

Comment: Hi jack, have you read the stackoverflow guide and rules? You are to show your code and phrase a question so you can get helped. Not just images.

Answer (score 0):

in button IBAction

```
MessageViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MessageViewControllerID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

and set ViewController Identifier as "MessageViewControllerID"

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot, again, what link?

Answer (score 0):

That slider is a parent view controller means use this code

*first way*

```
[(sliderclass*)self.parentViewController buttonAction];
```

*second Way*

```
[sliderMessageButton sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```